# XSLT: foreach with a nested IF clause, how to get "first TRUE result"?

Tags: xslt, foreach

I have a problem in the following XSLT Code.

`Foreach` loop generates 14 records, and 4 of them are selected by

`<xsl:if test="esperto = 'F'">`

clause.

```
<xsl:for-each select="../partite/risultatopartita">
  <xsl:if test="esperto = 'F'">
    <tr>
      <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <td rowspan="4" class='centra'>Favorite</td>
      </xsl:if>
      <td class='centra'>                            
        <xsl:value-of select="posizione"/>  
      </td>
      <td class='centra'>                            
        <xsl:value-of select="squadra1"/>
      </td>
      <td class='centra'>                            
        <xsl:value-of select="squadra2"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

I need that first `TD` (one with `rowspan="4"`) will be printed only first time, BUT "**first time that if clause is true, not first foreach iteration**".

Infact, `<xsl:if test="position()=1">` get first foreach itearation but is obviously possible that iteration that satisfies `<xsl:if test="esperto = 'F'">` could not be the first one of the foreach.

How to solve it?

---

Desired HMTL code is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="4" class='centra'>Favorite</td>
      <td class="centra">2</td>
      <td class="centra">fooText 1</td>
      <td class="centra">foofooText 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="centra">6</td>
      <td class="centra">fooText 2</td>
      <td class="centra">foofooText 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="centra">10</td>
      <td class="centra">fooText 3</td>
      <td class="centra">foofooText 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="centra">14</td>
      <td class="centra">fooText 4</td>
      <td class="centra">foofooText 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you show us the input XML and the expected output XML?

Comment: Sorry no... I don't have this... but I added desired html otuput

Comment: I'm confused about why you're using rowspan = 4. Do you know ahead of time that there will always be exactly 4 rows?

Comment: Yes! I know that with that particularly "if clause" it returns only 4 records ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
<xsl:for-each select="../partite/risultatopartita">
  <xsl:if test="esperto = 'F'">
```

you should simply put a predicate in the select expression, i.e. use

```
<xsl:for-each select="../partite/risultatopartita[esperto = 'F']">
```

That should do, at least as long your real code also has nothing but the `xsl:if` inside of the `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Thank you Martin, i tried also solution of Lingamurthy that runs correctly so is as valid as yours but finally I decided to accept yours because it's more compact. :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is quite tough to find an answer without an input XML.
You can use the following code instead of your for-each block:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../partite/risultatopartita">
<xsl:if test="esperto = 'F'">
    <tr>
        <xsl:if test="not(preceding-sibling::risultatopartita/esperto='F')">
            <td rowspan="4" class='centra'>Favorite</td>
        </xsl:if>
        <td class='centra'>                            
            <xsl:value-of select="posizione"/>  
        </td>
        <td class='centra'>                            
            <xsl:value-of select="squadra1"/>
        </td>
        <td class='centra'>                            
            <xsl:value-of select="squadra2"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thank you Lingamurthy, you were the first that proposed a solution and I tried your solution that ran correctly so I can absolutely say that it is a valid one. But in a second time I tried Martin's answer that is more compact. Thank you anyway for your help.